# Getting old data from mysql database when appending to div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a main page on which I have a button which opens a popup. When closing this popup then I have a script which calls to a php file to select data from the database. This selected data will be appended to a div in the main page:

```
 if (win.closed !== false) { 
    window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
    $.get("<?php echo $GLOBALFILESPHPFORJS ?>DBtoOCI.php", { ReferenceKey: Reference  } )
    .done(function( data ) { 
      console.log( data );
      $("#ItemData").append(data);
     });
```

The first time it nicely selects and appends the data. If I for example have a column called `animalname` which has 1 row with the data "Cat" then in my div I see cat. If I then delete the row uit of my database and add a row with a row called "Tiger" and then open and close the popup again, then get new data added to the div so it becomes: "Cat Tiger", But it is becomes "Cat Cat"! Why is this so?

Selecting data from database:

```
$sqlReturnExistingOCI = "SELECT * FROM animal WHERE animalname= ?";


      if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlReturnExistingOCI)) 
        {    
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $referencekey);

            if(!$stmt->execute()) 
            { 
                echo $stmt->error;
            } 
            else 
            { 

              $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                 echo $row['animalname'];
               }
              $stmt->free_result(); 
              $stmt->close; 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by saving every new data which I get from the popup window in the database with another reference number.

So before I open the popup I generate a unique number, add this to the url of the popup and then when saving the data to the database I use this number to save the data. And then if I reopen another popup it has a new unique reference number. Before this, I created 1 unique number and used this number to save data in the database and also used this number to delete the same rows from the database. So if I opened the popup and closed it, then it saved data with this unique number and also deleted this data with the same number but then if I reopen the popup and close again, then I see the old data again in the database, this is due caching I think.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clean the div first then append data for it `$("#ItemData").html('');`

```
if (win.closed !== false) { 
window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
$.get("<?php echo $GLOBALFILESPHPFORJS ?>DBtoOCI.php", { uniqueReferenceKey: Reference  } )
.done(function( data ) { 
  console.log( data );
  $("#ItemData").html('');
  $("#ItemData").append(data);
 });
```

Comment: I want to have the new data in the div and not delete it

Comment: as I see in your php code you get all data once. if you keep appending to div you will make it duplication in data even you didnt delete it form database.
the best way for solve this is to clean your div in each time you request data.
if you looking for another way to implement this you cant use `echo $row['animalname']; ` you have to use json and tell javascript what you want  to append and what you want to delete from div.

I can show  it for you if you like

Comment: in this dbtooci.php which i have I ehco the rows and afterwards delete the rows from DB, but if open again the dbtooci.php it selects and adds the same data so i guess there is an error in dbtoci.php